# Laravel 5.1 - Delayed Message Queueing

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.1, queueing

I'm trying to send a delayed message but it's not working, it gets into the jobs table but it stays there. Here is my code:

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.test', ['testVar' => 'hello'], function ($message){
   $message->to('*someaddress@hotmail.com', 'Someone');
   $message->subject('Subject');        
});
```

*: i use a real address

emails.test:

```
<p>  This is a test, an email test. </p>
```

.env:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

When i use *send* instead of *later*, the message is sent perfectly.

Do i have to modify something more to get this to work?

Comment: Are you running the queue listener? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener

Comment: I wasn't, thank you.

Comment: If the issue is solved, please post an answer and accept it. Cheers. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using this command to run the queue listener: `php artisan queue:listen`. Now it is working good. Thank you, [nathanmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5077591/nathanmac)